# Javascript Validate

Tags: validation, checkbox

I have a checkbox that I want to verify the checkbox (same names with different values) and to enable/disable if value is an `E` and it is checked.

```
function DisableETP() {
 var kk = document.getElementsByName('RQR')
 for (var i = 0; i < kk.length i++) {
     if (kk[i].value == 'E'
         and kk[i].checked == true) {
         document.getElementById('cp2').disabled = true
         document.getElementById('cp2').value = ""
         document.getElementById('rtp2').disabled = true
         document.getElementById('rtp2').value = ""
         document.getElementById('qty2').disabled = true
         document.getElementById('qty2').value = ""
         document.getElementById('cp3').disabled = true
         document.getElementById('cp3').value = ""
         document.getElementById('rtp3').disabled = true
         document.getElementById('rtp3').value = ""
         document.getElementById('qty3').disabled = true
         document.getElementById('qty3').value = ""
     } else {
         document.getElementById('cp2').disabled = false
         document.getElementById('cp2').value = ""
         document.getElementById('rtp2').disabled = false
         document.getElementById('rtp2').value = ""
         document.getElementById('qty2').disabled = false
         document.getElementById('qty2').value = ""
         document.getElementById('cp3').disabled = false
         document.getElementById('cp3').value = ""
         document.getElementById('rtp3').disabled = false
         document.getElementById('rtp3').value = ""
         document.getElementById('qty3').disabled = false
         document.getElementById('qty3').value = ""
     }
 }
```

Do I need to add `;` to the lines or...?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you don't strictly need semicolons, no.

However your first `if` statement is invalid because `and` is not correct javascript syntax, it should be `&&`.

```
if (kk[i].value == 'E' && kk[i].checked == true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should end each line in javascript with a ;

You also cannot use 'and' as a keyword in an if statement, you have to use && instead.

Its also best to check a boolean value with === instead of ==